# How to set a error handler safety net in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling

PHP offers the possibility to set customer error handlers with `set_error_handler("customError",E_USER_WARNING);` (for example).

How and where can I set some default error handlers for a Symfony 4 application to make sure I catch all unhandled errors?

I have noticed the Debug component which mentions `ErrorHandler::register();`. Is this the safety net I am looking for? If yes, where should I put that error handler registration call in my code? Should I modify the `index.php` page?

Answer (score 1):

Do the kernel events may be a solution to your issue ?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

You can check out all requests made on your kernel or controllers and even stop propagation of them.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php`, you can use it like below:

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {
    $errors = [
        [
            'status' => $code,
            'detail' => $e->getMessage()
        ]
    ];
    if ($app['debug'] === true) {
        $errors['file'] = $e->getFile();
        $errors['line'] = $e->getLine();
    }
    return new JsonResponse(['errors' => $errors]);
});
```

Comment: I don't think calls to  `trigger_error("An error has been triggered");` would be handled properly with this solution.

Comment: @JVerstry Well! You didn't mentioned that in question beforehand. But this the legitimate way of handling errors in Symfony and I personally using it in my app. Btw, you could use `Exceptions` in that case.

Comment: PHP's `trigger_error()` goes hand in hand with `set_error_handler()`